Dynamic block parsing + scrolling
I created a test email account. Tell me how to extract the dynamic values ​​of the file loading block and make normal scrolling. This is what I get, but for some reason no new values ​​are added when scrolling
import csv
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
 
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
 
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
 
chrome_driver_path = 'C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe'  
 
import os
if not os.path.exists(chrome_driver_path):
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"ChromeDriver not found at {chrome_driver_path}")
 
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
except TypeError:
    chrome_options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
 
login_url = 'https://account.mail.ru/login?fail=1'
 
driver.get(login_url)
 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
email_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="username"]')))
email_field.click()  
email_field.clear()  
email_field.send_keys('mdierickx@bk.ru')
 
next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-test-id="next-button"]')))
next_button.click()
 
password_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="password"]')))
password_field.click()  
password_field.clear()  
password_field.send_keys('Qzwxas12!')
 
login_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-test-id="submit-button"]')))
login_button.click()
 
time.sleep(5)
 
cloud_url = 'https://cloud.mail.ru/albums/ada729f1-181d-495f-86d5-86f2b5e44fa8'
driver.get(cloud_url)
time.sleep(5)  
 
toolbar_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="TOP_TOOLBAR_ID"]/div[2]/div[1]')))
toolbar_button.click()
 
list_option = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), "Списком")]')))
list_option.click()
 
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)  
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
 
download_icons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="download-icon"]')
 
download_urls = []
 
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
 
def intercept_requests(driver):
    logs = driver.get_log('performance')
    for log in logs:
        message = json.loads(log['message'])['message']
        if message['method'] == 'Network.requestWillBeSent':
            url = message['params']['request']['url']
            if 'datacloudmail.ru/attach/' in url:
                download_urls.append(url)
 
for icon in download_icons:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(icon).click(icon).perform()
    time.sleep(2)  
    intercept_requests(driver)
 
with open('download_urls.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['File Name', 'Download URL'])
    for url in download_urls:
        file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
        writer.writerow([file_name, url])
 
driver.quit()

The script itself clicks on all the 'download' icons one by one and catches requests where the direct download URL is located.
the list of transitions by icon is filled with 35 positions and when scrolling, no new positions are added to this block for transition... and scrolling doesn’t work clearly.
